# download a json data to a recyclerview into a fragment

Tags: android

I have been working into some android application and I am using 2 tabs which  have created one fragment to each and now I want to display a recyclerview into those fragments. But the problem is, when I download JSON data from a server, that data is successfully downloaded but its lost. I can not  see it in my recyclerview.
    I have tried so many times but nothing happend. here is the code:

```
This is my fragment:
public class Noticia extends Fragment {
     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.noticia, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)              view.findViewById(R.id.noticiasRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        BuscaNoticia();
        return view;
    }

   private void BuscaNoticia() {
        new NoticiaAsyncTask().execute();
    }

class NoticiaAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Aguarde...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            JSONParse jsonParse = new JSONParse();
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParse.makehttpRequest(url, "POST");

            Log.d("Dados retornados: ", jsonObject.toString());

            arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

            try {
                sucesso = jsonObject.getInt("Sucesso");
                if (sucesso == 1) {
                    jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Noticias");

                    for (int i = 1; i <= jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject dadosJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        NoticiaItem noticiaItem = new NoticiaItem();

                        noticiaItem.setTitulo(dadosJson.getString("titulo"));
                        noticiaItem.setNoticia(dadosJson.getString("noticia"));
                        noticiaItem.setData(simpleDateFormat.parse(dadosJson.getString("dados")));
                        noticiaItem.setCategoria(dadosJson.getString("Categoria"));
                        // adiciona na lista
                        arrayList.add(noticiaItem);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  noticiaAdapter = new NoticiaAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList);
                  recyclerView.setAdapter(noticiaAdapter);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}


And here is the adapter:
public class NoticiaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoticiaAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    // inflator to my recyclerview layout
    private Context context;
    private List<NoticiaItem> list;

    // construtor
    public NoticiaAdapter(Context context, List<NoticiaItem> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview, null);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // esta eh a informacao que vem do banco. pego e seto no textviews dentro do recyclerview
        NoticiaItem noticia = list.get(position);

        // setando os dados do recyclerview
        holder.Titulo.setText(noticia.getTitulo());
        holder.Paragrafo.setText(noticia.getNoticia());
        holder.Hora.setText(String.valueOf(noticia.getData()));
        holder.Categoria.append(noticia.getCategoria());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != list ? list.size() : 0);
    }

    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // RecyclerView widgets
        protected ImageView Imagem;
        protected TextView Titulo;
        protected TextView Paragrafo;
        protected TextView Hora;
        protected TextView Categoria;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.Imagem = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_noticia);
            this.Titulo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titulo_noticia);
            this.Paragrafo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.paragrafo_noticia);
            this.Hora = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hora_noticia);
            this.Categoria = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoria_noticia);
        }
    }
}
 And the Json data am trying to download is:
{
Noticias: [
{
id: "1",
titulo: "Titulo Noticia",
noticia: "Noticia nova",
data: "2015-07-18",
categoria: "1"
},
{
id: "2",
titulo: "Titulo Noticia",
noticia: "Noticia nova",
data: "2015-07-18",
categoria: "1"
},
{
id: "3",
titulo: "Titulo Noticia",
noticia: "Noticia nova",
data: "2015-07-18",
categoria: "1"
},
{
id: "4",
titulo: "Importante",
noticia: "Mova Noticia importante",
data: "2015-07-20",
categoria: "2"
}
],
Sucesso: 1
}

I don't  know whats can be wrong here. Help please
```

Comment: what does noticia.getTitulo() returns you in onBindViewHolder method?

Comment: Why you use runOnUiThread? Is there a special reason?

Comment: @hariszaman: noticia.getTitulo() returns a string. its like am just passing an string that i get from a noticia list

Comment: @Cuneyt: am new in android so i saw that runOnUiThread because i saw it on some toturiais . its because of that that my data dosent apair?

Comment: so it returns the correct string? for example if the api json returns "test" it is "test" in their or something else?

Comment: @hariszaman thanks for trying to help me but i did resolve the problem. it was because the date parsing that made this stuff went wrong . but thanks at all

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **runOnUiThread** from **onPostExecute** as it is on same thread just update the UI there. More Info check here [Android AyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)